# Value Error: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I have tried to convert the values in the column `company_size` and tried to different approaches around it and still get the ValueError. Do anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
handle_df.loc[handle_df['company_size'].isin(['I prefer not to answer',"I don't know"]),['company_size']]=np.NaN
handle_df.loc[handle_df['company_size'] == 'Fortune 1000 (1,000+)' ,['company_size']]='1000'
handle_df.loc[handle_df['company_size'] == '1/25/2013' ,['company_size']]='1-25'
handle_df.loc[handle_df['company_size'] == '1/5/2014' ,['company_size']]='1-5'
handle_df.loc[handle_df['company_size'] == '6/15/2014' ,['company_size']]='6-15'

handle_df.loc[handle_df['company_size'].isin(['Student',"Other (not working, consultant, etc.)"]),['company_size']]='1'

handle_df['company_size'] = handle_df['company_size'].map(lambda x:str(x).replace(" to ",'-'))

handle_df = process_data_range(handle_df,'company_size',dropna=False)
```

Full error traceback

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-84fdd9e45198> in <module>
      9 handle_df['company_size'] = handle_df['company_size'].map(lambda x:str(x).replace(" to ",'-'))
     10 
---> 11 handle_df = process_data_range(handle_df,'company_size',dropna=False)
     12 

<ipython-input-11-510bc7e7040d> in process_data_range(df, feature, dropna)
     28     # for na value,I mark them as 'NaN'
     29     change_to_midpoint = lambda x: np.average([float(i) for i in x.split("-")]) if "-" in x else np.NaN if x == "" else float(x)
---> 30     df[feature] = df[feature].map(change_to_midpoint)
     31 
     32     if dropna:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3907         January     History     Final exam      A
   3908         February    Geography   Final exam      B
-> 3909         March       History     Coursework      A
   3910         April       Geography   Coursework      C
   3911         dtype: object

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
    935         **bins**
    936 
--> 937         Bins can be useful for going from a continuous variable to a
    938         categorical variable; instead of counting unique
    939         apparitions of values, divide the index in the specified

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-11-510bc7e7040d> in <lambda>(x)
     27     # if age range ,change it to the midpoint
     28     # for na value,I mark them as 'NaN'
---> 29     change_to_midpoint = lambda x: np.average([float(i) for i in x.split("-")]) if "-" in x else np.NaN if x == "" else float(x)
     30     df[feature] = df[feature].map(change_to_midpoint)
     31 

<ipython-input-11-510bc7e7040d> in <listcomp>(.0)
     27     # if age range ,change it to the midpoint
     28     # for na value,I mark them as 'NaN'
---> 29     change_to_midpoint = lambda x: np.average([float(i) for i in x.split("-")]) if "-" in x else np.NaN if x == "" else float(x)
     30     df[feature] = df[feature].map(change_to_midpoint)
     31 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: In which line are you getting the ValueError?

Comment: Well, the error message indicates that you have some empty strings `''` in whatever column you are trying to convert to `float`.  I don't see any float conversions in the code you posted - it would help if you edited the question to include the full code, input data, expected output, and full error traceback (aka a [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have data like "-" or "nnn-" or "-nnn" where nnn is any number.  As 0x5453 says you are trying to do float('') on something that has come from from the data.